# Write node value back into the xml file after reading it and incrementing it by one in PHP

Tags: php, xml

Thanks for devoting time. I am very new in php like an Infant.

I have a Xml file counter.xml like.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<countIt>
<number>50</number></countIt>
```

I can read this file By SimpleXML as follows:

```
$content=simplexml_load_file("counter.xml");
$addid=$content->countIt->number;
```

Now I want to read this value (number---> id i.e. 55) after some operations like increment by 1, I want to save this new value of the node in file too.
that means the new value must reflect into xml file.

I am stuck with this problem. I tried DOM but I got only help to create a new Xml File.

Please Help

**SOLUTION:**

```
<?php
$domObj= new DOMDocument(); 
$domObj->load("counter.xml");
$value= $domObj->getElementsByTagName("countIt");
$newVal = 0 ;
foreach( $value as $val) 
{ 
 $ints = $val->getElementsByTagName("number"); 
 $intVal  = $ints->item(0)->nodeValue; 
 $newVal = $intVal+1;
 $domObj->getElementsByTagName("number")->item(0)->nodeValue = $newVal; 
 $domObj->save('counter.xml');
}  
?>
```

Comment: open and read file search for value and replace it

Comment: the logic is obvious but the code lines, those i have no clue about

Comment: try http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-XML-Replacing-Node-P416.html

Answer (score 0):

This example makes use of the `xpath()` function to select the node to be changed:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x

// get the node
$target = $xml->xpath("/countIt/number");

// change it
$target[0][0] = (int)$target[0] + 1;
```

see it working: https://eval.in/153679

Comments:

- `xpath` will return an array to `$target`, in this example it has 1 element.
- `$target[0] = 50`, for safety, I cast it to integer with `(int)` before adding
- for saving the new XML, look into `simplexml` on PHP.net for `asXML()`.

Comment: i figured a much easier and more general way to do it there is my solution posted under the question